# Can a webapp connect to mosquitto?

Tags: nginx, web-applications, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a mosquitto_sub running on background on serverA, let's say with topic "TEST", port 1883.
I followed [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-plus-iot-load-balancing-mqtt/) to use nginx as a stream proxy to mosquitto, on ServerB.

Testing the setup sending a message to ServerB, using mosquitto_pub, the message is received and displayed correctly on serverA.

Now I'd like that a webapp running on serverC could receive the mqtt messages I send using a websocket, as far as I understand that nginx setup is made exactly for this purpose because browser can't use directly mqtt protocol.

I did two tests:

- pointing the websocket to ServerB stream (wss://serverB:1883)
- pointing the websocket to nginx reverse proxy with this config:

.

```
...
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ...

    location /webapp/websocket {
            proxy_set_header HOST $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass_request_headers on;
            proxy_pass http://serverB:1883/;
            proxy_http_version 1.0;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 1800s;
    }

}
```

With both the websocket doesn't work, with error 502 Bad Gateway.
My questions are, did I understand wrong and can it be done?
Does it say error 502 just because the webapp must be programmed to specify the topic to listen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mosquitto broker supports MQTT over WebSockets, but it has to be on a separate port to native MQTT over TCP.

So if Mosquitto is normally listening on port 1883, you need to pick a different port to run the MQTT over WebSockets listener. e.g.

```
listener 1883

listener 8083
protocol websockets
```

You would then need to update the port in the `proxy_pass` entry to match.

Comment: Thanks for the useful tip, but still 502. mosquitto pub/sub is working with the new websocket port.

Comment: My bad, the websocket is listening. But how to specify the topic now?

Comment: Topics are not URL paths, you need to run a JavaScript MQTT client in the browser